# How to return grades and custom values from LTI (learning tools interoperability) Tool Provider to Moodle

Tags: php, moodle, lti

I am developing **Tool Provider** (TP) of **Learning Tools Interoperability** (LTI) **version 1.1.1** using **PHP**.

I want to pass grades and custom values from **TP** back to **Moodle LMS** (ie. the Tool Consumer).

Knowing that `lis_result_sourcedid` and `lis_outcome_service_url` should be used, but I don't know how to make use of these parameters in the TP programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need make a POST request from the **TP** to the **TC** using the `lis_outcome_service_url` as destination URI. The format of the body needs to conform the one defined in the LTI 1.1 standard (see [here](https://www.imsglobal.org/specs/ltiv1p1/implementation-guide#toc-37)) which, among others, uses the `lis_result_sourcedid` parameter as a way to identify the item you are grading in the **TC** gradebook.